# split list of data frames by group, apply function, combine into list

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, data-manipulation

I have a list of data frames, each with a unique name that can be used to look up its group identity. I want to split this list, by the group identities, average the data frames in each group, and return it all into a list of data frames renamed by group. The following code does what I want, but I feel like it uses one too many 'ply' funcitons.  There has to be a simpler / faster / more elegant solution than bashing the list with 'plyr' until it comPLYes (bwahaha).

```
l<-list(a.txt=data.frame(x=c(1,4), y=c(5,5)),
     b.txt=data.frame(x=c(5,3), y=c(4,5)),
     c.txt=data.frame(x=c(1,1), y=c(6,2)),
     d.txt=data.frame(x=c(9,9), y=c(4,1)))

e<-data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c","d"), Grp=c("amb","amb","sam","sam"))
f<-unique(e$Grp)

new_l<-llply(seq_along(f), function(x,n,i){as.data.frame(
             aaply(laply(x[paste(e$ID[e$Grp%in%n[i]],".txt", sep="")], as.matrix), 
                      c(2,3), mean))}, x=l, n=f) 
names(new_l)<-gids
```

If this has been answered point me in the right direction, because I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the ID's by Grp and then for each set of ID's get the corresponding components of l and take their mean.

```
Mean <- function(x) Reduce("+", x) / length(x)
tapply(e$ID, e$Grp, function(id) Mean(l[paste0(id, ".txt")]))
```

giving:

```
$amb
    x   y
1 3.0 4.5
2 3.5 5.0

$sam
  x   y
1 5 5.0
2 5 1.5
```

**Note:** A simplification is possible if it were known that the ID's line up exactly with the components of l, as in the question.  In that case one could split l on e$Grp:

```
tapply(l, e$Grp, Mean)
```

Comment: I agree, I was thinking about that wrong. It was the sample ids that needed to be split

Comment: Added Note to answer.

Comment: In this case that would work, but I don't want to assume that for the non toy application.

Answer (score 1):

if i am understanding your question correctly the following should work. This also assumes that the order of your `e` dataframe is the same order as your `l` list of dataframes. Otherwise I can edit the solution to fit your needs.

```
res <- lapply(1:length(f),function(m) Reduce('+',l[e$Grp==f[m]])/length(l[e$Grp==f[m]]))
names(res) <- f

$amb
    x   y
1 3.0 4.5
2 3.5 5.0

$sam
  x   y
1 5 5.0
2 5 1.5
```